# Vue js - source available to component

Tags: javascript, components, vuejs2, state-management

I have created a source in my main app.js file

```
let source = {
    selectedTalent: 0,
};


 var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 components:{
  Navigation:navigation,
```

I want the source to be available in my navigation component. I aways get a not defined error.

How do I get this to work. Do I have to pass as a prop? I though this would be globally available as 'source'

My component is imported like this as I am using a custom webpack

```
import navigation from './components/nav.vue';
```

This is the only difference I can see from the example in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export and import that `source` object correctly, otherwise its scope is within the `app.js` script. That *scoping* is pretty much what Webpack does.

Example:

`source.js`

```
export default let source = {
    selectedTalent: 0,
};
```

`navigation.component.js`

```
import source from '../path/to/source/'

/* your code for the component here */
```

And then you could avoid declaring `source` in your `app.js` as you seem not to be using it in there.